# Python file size not the same as array

Tags: python, binaryfiles

Another python question... I'm writing a script that scans an array of text files and calculates the relative frequency of tetragraphs within the text (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragraph). The purpose of this code is to integrate into an automatic substitution cipher solver.

My code appears to be working - it correctly scans through all lines of text and makes the appropriate calculations. The issue I have is with saving the array into a file and then reloading it. Assuming an alphabet of 26 characters (A-Z), the tetragraphs array should be 26 ^ 4 = 456976 and so the resulting file size should be 456976 bytes. My code however seems to be creating a file that is 456972 bytes, which is 4 bytes too small. My first though was an indexing issue on the loop that writes the bytes, but the commented out print statement tells me that the loop appears to be executed the correct number of times.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Code:

```
def tools_createtetra(infiles, outfile = 'tetra.log', alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', scale = 16):

    maxval = 0

    alphalen = int(len(alphabet))

    tetras = [0] * alphalen
    for i in range(alphalen):
        tetras[i] = [0] * alphalen
        for j in range(alphalen):
            tetras[i][j] = [0] * alphalen
            for k in range(alphalen):
                tetras[i][j][k] = [0] * alphalen

    for i in range(len(infiles)):
        fp = open(infiles[i])
        filetext = fp.read()
        filetext = u''.join(c for c in filetext if c in alphabet.join(alphabet.lower())).upper()

        for l in range(len(filetext) - 3):
            tetras[alphabet.find(filetext[l])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 1])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 2])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 3])] += 1
            if tetras[alphabet.find(filetext[l])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 1])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 2])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 3])] > maxval:
                maxval = tetras[alphabet.find(filetext[l])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 1])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 2])][alphabet.find(filetext[l + 3])]

        fp.close()

    maxval = int(math.log(maxval))
    scalefactor = maxval / scale

    fp = open(outfile, "wb")

    for i in range(alphalen):
        for j in range(alphalen):
            for k in range(alphalen):
                for l in range(alphalen):
                    if tetras[i][j][k][l] != 0:
                        tetras[i][j][k][l] = int(math.log(tetras[i][j][k][l]) / scalefactor)
                    fp.write(bytes(chr(tetras[i][j][k][l]), 'ascii'))
                    # print(alphabet[i], alphabet[j], alphabet[k], alphabet[l], ':',tetras[i][j][k][l])

    fp.close()
```

EDIT: Here is the code I used to calculate the length of the file... maybe the error is here? This is where I was getting my figures from. If I loop through until len(tetrastring) then I get an indexing error trying to load the array...

```
fp = open(tetrafile)
tetrastring = fp.read()
fp.close()

print(len(tetrastring))
```

Comment: Is there anything missing from the files? By inspection. 4 bytes is a very small difference so it could be only 1 character, really. Or nothing at all.

Comment: Nothing obvious - but it is hard to tell... because the tetragraphs like 'aaaa' and 'zzzz' are pretty much never found in normal text, the start and end of the file is a bunch of zeros. If I look at the file in a hex editor then it *looks* right, but I can't tell if there's a small offset in there or not.

Comment: I've commented the loop that reads your input and tested. It works here: -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 456976 Dec 17 20:59 tetra.log. Using python 3.2.3 in Ubuntu 12.04.3

Comment: When I run this code it does produce a 456976-byte output file. Maybe the code that you are having problems with is not exactly like this?

Comment: No... its fine too... It prints 456976

Comment: If change the measuring code to open with mode `rb`, does the issue go away?

Comment: I tried that but the read function returned an int instead of a string? I also tried len(tetrastring.encode('utf-8')) with no luck?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely caused by unicode characters throwing off the length measurements.  The *len()* function on a unicode string gives you the number of code points after combining characters (such as an "umlaut" and an "O" which together count as a single character).  A [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) can also account for a four-byte difference.

The `u''.join()` in the posted code is the hint that unicode issues may be the source of the length measurement discrepancy.

Comment: But the output file is all numbers encoded as bytes, not unicode. I don't think this is relevant at all.

Comment: Well, he is not opening the file in binary mode... try using fp = open(tetrafile, "rb") in your second program

Comment: Yeah he is: `fp = open(outfile, "wb")`

Comment: Sorry, in the program that is verifying the length

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that edit yet. You may be right. If the issue is that *the measuring program* is misinterpreting things as unicode that are really binary, then this answer may be right. That should probably be a made a bit clearer though.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this might be the issue... I've tried switching it to 'rb' but the read function doesn't seem to like that (read returns an integer not a string). Is there a simple way to read the whole file into a string and not do the unicode conversion?

Comment: I tried 'len(tetrastring.encode('utf-8')) but it gives the same result?